# Has anyone tried literate programming for C#, with Lyx and noweb

Tags: c#, literate-programming, lyx, noweb

I came across [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/devdev/archive/2006/01/23/516431.aspx) blog post yesterday, and it once again made me want to give [literate programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) a try.

Has anyone else tried doing literate programming for C#? I'm wondering about trying [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) + [noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/), but wondered if you might have other experience or suggestions.

Comment: I don't really "get it".... looks like code with a lot of comments to me :-)

Comment: No, it's text with bits of code, check out the blog post linked in the question. I think it is very good for *communicating* code to someone else. Obviously, with no intellisense, no code formatting, no debugger, it's a long shot, but I'd like to try.

Comment: Hmm, I have this idea brewing for using markdown for literate programming :)

Comment: how are things going with literate programming? have you continued?

Comment: For C# there's [LiterateCS](https://github.com/johtela/LiterateCS). Haven't tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get [Leo](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/front.html), the outlining editor, and make noweb files.  Noweb can make HTML that can be your online documentation and it can make source files that are numbered like your noweb input.  You can edit the noweb or the source.  If you edit the source, Leo can update your changes back into the noweb file.  Noweb can also make TEX files for really pretty printing.

Noweb is so simple its users guide fits on one side of one sheet of paper.  Leo is one of those GUI tools you already know how to use ... has lotsa tricks if you want them.

Both are free!

Comment: Link seems to be down/unavailable.

Comment: Leo is now on GitHub: https://github.com/leo-editor/leo-editor